# integral identity with laplacian squared

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, laplacian

I found this exercise but I am not able to solve it: let $n > 1$  a positive integer .Prove that for any $u \; \colon \, \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with $ u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with compact support the following equality holds:

$\sum_{1 \leq i,j  \leq n} \int _{\mathbb{R}^n}|\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}|^2\, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |\Delta u| ^2 \, dx$

where $\Delta u $ denotes the laplacian of $u$. I would need a solution or at least a hint  for this because I really do not know how to do it.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Sorry , I tried to be more clear now

Comment: Can you prove it if $u \in C^4(\mathbf R^n)$ with compact support?

Comment: Yes , If I have higher regularty I just need to use by parts integration and I would solve the problem ,I suppose

Comment: That's absolutely right. Do you know about regularization? (or mollification?)

Comment: I barely know the definition of mollified functions. But if you could please explain me how to use it in this case I will give my best to fill in the gaps

Comment: Evans' PDE book is a good place to look.